# iOS GLKit: set GLKBaseEffect texture with camera output

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, glkit

I have set up an AVCapture session, and in the delegate method, use the following code to try to set a GLKBaseEffect texture with the output, however all I get is black. What should I do to make it work?

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer (CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

effect.texture2d0.name = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(pixelBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** I don't think you can use camera output with `GLKBaseEffect` — data from the camera is in biplanar YUV format, so you need a custom fragment shader to convert that to RGB at render time, and `GLKBaseEffect` doesn't do custom shaders.

It looks like there's some API confusion here, so read on if you'd like more background...

Though the `CVOpenGLESTexture` type is derived from `CVPixelBuffer`, the image buffers you get back from `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer` aren't automatically OpenGL ES textures. You need to create textures from image buffers each time you get a frame from the camera using `CVOpenGLESTextureCache`.

Apple's [`GLCameraRipple`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011222) sample code illustrates how to do this. Here's a quick overview:

1. After setting up a GL context, the `setupAVCapture` method calls `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate` to create a texture cache tied to that context.
2. In `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`, they get the image buffer from the sample buffer using `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer`, then create two OpenGL ES textures from it using the texture cache's `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` function. You need two textures because the image buffer has YUV color data in two bitplanes.
3. Each texture gets bound for rendering right after being created, using `glBindTexture`. Generally, you could replace a `glBindTexture` call with setting a `GLKBaseEffect`'s `texture2d0.name` and telling it to `prepareToDraw`, but `GLKBaseEffect` can't render YUV.
4. Draw with the two bound textures, using a shader program whose fragment shader first makes a YUV vector by combining components from the Y and UV textures, then does a simple matrix multiply to convert it to an RGB pixel color according to the HDTV color space spec.

Because you need a custom fragment shader for the YUV to RGB conversion, `GLKBaseEffect` won't help you. However, as the `GLCameraRipple` sample shows, the custom shaders you'd need to write aren't that scary.

Comment: Hi rickster, thanks for this explanation of the Camera Ripple app. There is something I can't get my head around - if I try to do the drawing myself, just to simply draw the texture on the screen with two triangles, I just get a giant blob flashing one color! ...oops no way to insert code in a comment... I make the tex co-ords a Z shape with x and y values from 0.0 to 1.0 and the vertices a Z with values from -1.0 to 1.0, then draw a triangle strip using the attribute pointer call for both sets of vertices.